# How to use Azure Pipeline to "Push" a docker image to Azure Container Registry?

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

Here is my scenario/usecase:

Pull a docker image from docker hub and push it to Azure Container Registry. Note, I do not have to build the docker image

I am following this documentation but some things are not clear

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/push-image?view=azure-devops#azure-container-registry

Here is the azure pipeline yaml snippet

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: |
      $(dockerHub)
    repository: $(imageName)
    command: push
    tags: |
      test1
      test2
```

What i don't understand is, where is the link between Azure Container Registry and Docker Hub such that it satisfies the link between source and destination?

Could someone please clarify and provide me a working yaml snippet to get my job done?

thanks!

Comment: You have to pull the image first.

Comment: Do you create a **service connection** in Azure DevOps? If you create a pipeline using the predefined configuration (e.g., `Docker - Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry`), the service connection is created automatically. Otherwise, you have to make it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

why you need a pipeline for that? If you have a ACR, use ACR Tasks to schedule automated import of images from any Registry to your ACR:

task.yaml

```
version: v1.1.0
steps:
  - cmd: az acr import --name my_registry --source SOURCE --image IMAGE --force
```

Create the task:

```
export REGISTRY_NAME=my_registry
cat task.yaml | \
    az acr task create -n scheduled-import -r $REGISTRY_NAME \
            -f - \
            -c /dev/null \
            --schedule "0 * * * *"
```

Documentation:

1. [ACR Tasks reference: YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-reference-yaml)
2. [az acr task create](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cli/azure/acr/task?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acr_task_create)

Comment: "az acr import" should probably be "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli acr import", as the "az" image has been moved to the Microsoft Container Registry. I didn't edit the existing answer since I haven't tried it personally.